# Diagnosing ethernet cable problems

Tags: ethernet, cabling

(Please excuse me if I use the improper terminology; I'm an amateur who knows enough to be dangerous, but not enough to really be useful)

I'm setting up a home network and am having issues with getting all of my wall plates to work. I have 6 throughout my house located in strategic places, but only one of them is working.

I've verified that it's a cable problem, because I can plug my laptop directly in to my switch and access the network, but if I go through the wall plate, I don't get any connection.

However, I'm reasonably confident that everything is wired correctly (568B), because I've used a tone generator on both ends of each wall plate cable and see the lights come on in the proper 1-8 sequence, with no skips, just like it does with the wall plate that *does* work.

I'm at a loss as to how I should diagnose the issue further. The wiring seems to be correct on all the wall plates, but only one is actually working. Where should I be looking next?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su]. There is far more to a proper cable installation than electrical connectivity, and a proper cable tester costs several thousand dollars.

Comment: Sadly, home networking is off-topic here. You can try asking on Superuser.com

Comment: @RonMaupin respectfully I disagree. The question is only incidentally about a home network. This is a question about how I diagnose a problematic Ethernet cable. If it makes you feel better, I work from home so I could just as easily replace all instances of "home" with "work" 

Comment: If you must ask that question, you don't have the knowledge or tools to properly do this. A proper tester will tell you where the cable is failing. You can permanently ruin a cable with too much pulling force, or having it kinked at one time. Home networking is off-topic here because you don't have the correct information to tell us if  The primary tests are: Wire Map, Length, Insertion Loss, NEXT, PSNEXT, ELFEXT, PSELFEXT, Return Loss, Propagation Delay, and Delay Skew. You need to determine which is/are out of spec. Questions about home networking are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: If you disagree, you can always bring it up for discussion on [meta]. It's possible that, like often happens in home networking, the cable was stapled to the studs, as is required for power and telephone cables. That will cause a data cable to fail the necessary tests. In any case, the questions is not about "_professionally managed networks in a business environment._"

Answer (score 1):

You are very likely missing a connection on one or more of the eight wires needed for gigabit ethernet or perhaps two are "swapped" i.e. in the wrong places.  You could use primitive technology like a multimeter on ohms/resistance function but I would highly suggest borrowing or renting a simple tester.  You send a signal through the conductors on one end (battery powered) and the receiver lights up if/when each conductor is connected correctly.  [https://www.amazon.com/HDE-HDE-H11-Network-Cable-Tester/dp/B000P1OA1O](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000P1OA1O)

---

If you want to shoot from the hip, remove and re punch down all your conductors at the female end and/or crimp new male ends on (if you have done that part yourself - if not, leave them be).  Remember, there are two standards - 568A and 568B.  Be sure you're using the same standard **at both ends of each cable!**